# logarithmic chart with 0 values

Tags: highcharts, logarithm

I have created a new logarithmic graph using Highcharts.
But from time to time I have 0 values :( where there are no players in my game.

Q: How can i display 0 value on logarithmic chart? (note: log0 = infinite)

I have changed all values from 0 to 0.01, but now it appears when all values are 0.01
the graph looks like:

[image]

Comment: I tried using formatter as was suggested here - did not work for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181588/highcharts-best-way-to-handle-and-display-zero-or-negative-values-in-a-line#_=_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all of your 0 values to `null`.