# Logarithmic Interpolation and 0 values

Tags: logarithm

I have a function that interpolates between two values on a logarithmic scale, so as to have more values around the lower end of my values.

```
public void logspace(double lower, double upper, double amount) {
    double start = Math.log(Math.min(lower, upper));
    double end = Math.log(Math.max(lower, upper));
    double step = (end - start) / amount;

    for(double level = start; level <= end; level += step) {
        System.out.println(Math.exp(level));
    }
}
```

However I do not know how to correctly handle if one of the values is 0. If one of the values if 0 then we end up with -Infinity as one of our boundaries, which produces unexpected results.

I can't simply use 0 in place of `log(0)` as this would result in 0 values between 0 and 1, as `log(1)` is 0.

How can I produce logarithmically spaced values between two arbitrary values?

Comment: You can't, as you have discovered. Would you be willing to consider some other function?

Comment: Yes, I just need `n` values between two values, with more values being towards one end.

Comment: You could add a constant to the upper and lower...say 1000 and do the math with this value. The level would then need to adjust for the altered start point.

Comment: From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498740/logarithmic-chart-with-0-values?rq=1

Change all of your 0 values to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different formulas depending on whether your value is above or below some arbitrary cutoff. With a little care those two formulas will have the same value at the cutoff point.

For example, we'll assume your data doesn't have any interesting values below 1.0. If we use the log scale for everything above 1.0, the lowest output will be 0.0. Then for everything below 1.0, we switch to a linear scale.

```
public double logscale(double value) {
    if (value > 1.0)
        return Math.log(value);
    else
        return value - 1.0;
}
```

You can improve the linear portion of the formula by using a multiplier to set the slope of the curve from that point.

It's also possible to use something other than linear below the inflection point, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.