# Highcharts: Displaying zero values in logarithmic scale

Tags: charts, highcharts, zero, logarithm

I am working with logarithmic scale in the y-axis

I know that log(0) doesn't exist but I need to draw 0 values, and I need a log scale.

I read in other answers that changing the zero values to `null` solve the problem, but it is not working for me. See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/QEK3x/15/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although not perfect, the best I came up with was to set the zero point to 0.0001 and then set the y-axis min to 0.0001:

http://jsfiddle.net/6LHT8/

```
yAxis: {        
    min:0.0001,
    type: 'logarithmic'
},

series: [{
    data: [100,10,0.0001,0.1,0.01,0.1]
}]
```

Also, this answer may nelp:
[Highcharts - best way to handle and display zero (or negative) values in a line chart series with logarithmic Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181588/highcharts-best-way-to-handle-and-display-zero-or-negative-values-in-a-line)

Comment: Actually I tried that. But 1e-20 instead of 0.0001, which is very high for my case. But unfortunately that was not accepted because the users are going to see that is not 0, and being exactly 0 or not is important in this case.

Comment: Refer to the link I posted. I think it will fix that for you.