# Highcharts: Logarithmic chart with Y Axis [100, 99.9, 99, 90, 0]

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use Highcharts to generate our website's availability information.
The Y axis is availability in percentage, the expected labels are:

```
[100, 99.9, 99, 90, 0]
```

code:
http://jsfiddle.net/2E9vF/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "AVAILABILITY %"
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return 100-this.value;
                }
            },
            type: 'logarithmic',
            reversed:true,
            min:0.01,
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#CCCCCC',
                width: 2,
                value: 0.1,
                dashStyle: 'ShortDot'
            },{
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 1,
                dashStyle: 'ShortDot'
            },{
                color: '#CCCCCCC',
                width: 2,
                value: 10,
                dashStyle: 'ShortDot'
            }],
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return 'x:'+ this.x +'<br>'+
                    'y:'+ (100-this.y);
            }
        },        
        series: [{
            // real data:
            // [90, 98, 99.7, 100, 100, 99.9, 99.7, 90, 91, 98, 96, 97.3]
            data: [10, 2, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 10, 9, 2, 4, 2.7]        
        }]
    });
});
```

However, I have two issues that I need help with:

1. I cannot draw 100 in the y axis
2. Orginal data with value 100 cannot be shown in the chart

Here is the expected chart:
http://www.shareimage.ro/images/0j1o0bnccavkqds8icuy.jpg
[image]

Comment: Don't make it a logarithmic scale?

Comment: The idea for y axis is [100-0, 100-0.1, 100-1, 100-10, 100-100]. [0, 0.1, 1, 10, 100] are logarithmic scale. Or is there any other way to do the same thing without logarithmic y axis?

Comment: Most of the data range between 100 to 90. Log y is used to increase the space to make data trend more clear. If not using log y, the data series looks like almost a flat line. I understand there are many ways (like set min and max) to visualize this information. However, I would like to know if there's any solution based on current design (Y is 100, 99.9, 99, 90, 0. Each of the y label distance is the same (the pixel between 100 and 99.9 is the same with 90 to 10) Thanks.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447408/highcharts-displaying-zero-values-in-logarithmic-scale ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general negative numbers and zero-based are not supported, but you can workaround this: http://jsfiddle.net/2E9vF/2/

In steps:

- Assume that value 0 will be represented as other one, for example 0.001 (or lower)
- Set min for yAxis to that value
- Update formatters for tooltip and yAxis.labels accordingly:

  ```
  tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
          if(this.y === 0.001) {
              return 'x:'+ this.x +'<br>'+  'y:100';
          } else {
              return 'x:'+ this.x +'<br>'+  'y:'+ (100-this.y);
          }
      }
  },
  ```

And:

```
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.isFirst) {
                      return 100;  
                } 
                return 100-this.value;
            }
        }
    }
```