# how to put the minimum value equal 0 in axes x in Chart C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, charts, logarithm

good afternoon!

I would like to know if it is possible to put the value zero in scale in chart
The chart is in logarithmic with base 10 and value maximum is 100 and minimum 0.001, I want to put o minimum value in zero. 
Here's an image of the graph tasks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI6Ic.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

"On a logarithmic scale, each tick mark on the scale is the previous tick mark multiplied by some number -base- (Wiki)."

So the 0 does not exist in log!

What you can do is to put something very close to 0 but not a 0.

Somehow this question could be considered a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447408/highcharts-displaying-zero-values-in-logarithmic-scale), have a look.

Comment: thanks! I will to do this